# \includegraphics and having "." in the image file name

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

I'm using the graphicx package with

```
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt][c]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example2.2}}
\end{center}
```

to insert images into my LaTeX file.

However, I get an error because of the "." in the image file name "example2.2". If I change it to "example2", then it works fine. Is there any way to use file names with periods in them without getting an error?

Comment: no. after `.` latex search for file name extension (as `pdf`, `png`, `jpeg` ...).

Comment: Use the grffile package (but I would avoid dots).

Comment: Out of curiosity: does writing `example2\string.2` work?

Comment: @Seamus Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @campa You could discern one of the solutions already posted from that question, but it does not directly address this, so I think also having this question is of benefit.

Comment: @campa That question is specifically asking about having more than one dot in the image file name; I'm asking about having any dot in the image file name. This question and its answers more directly address the latter.

Comment: @ThePointer You are also asking about multiple dots in the file name (the real filename, not what you write in your document)

Comment: @samcarter Oh, of course. My apologies.

Comment: @campa That's fine. I should have done it earlier, but I totally misread the other question. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{{example2.2}.png}
\end{document}
```

if png file etc...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `grffile` package was born mainly for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example2.2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will probably break all sorts of things, but...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\.{.}
\catcode`.\active\def.{\.}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example2.2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, no, no, no, no.

Comment: @egreg --- I thought you might turn up and say that!

Comment: That was the minimal number of no's for the comment to be accepted, but you can add as many as you like. At least don't redefine `\.`: ``\catcode`.=\active\edef.{\string.}``

Comment: @egreg --- I didn't know that `\.` was defined, so I learned something today.